# In mysql Get the count of left and right child of root user

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, binary-tree

Is there any way to get the total no of left and right children by its parent id till "N" no of child level.

[image: binary tree]

Here is my user table where i am storing the parent-child info with leg(left/right) position

[image: user table]

Where:

1. `referral_id`: is the id of parent user of child user
2. `left_child_id`: is the id of child user who joined the user on left leg
3. `right_child_id`: is the id of child user who joined the user on right leg.
4. `position_to_referral`: is the position name(left/right leg) where he joined the parent user

Any help or any kind of suggestion is welcome.

I can get the count using below php code but i want to get the count directly from mysql

```
function countChildren($parentId, $Nlevel, $tempLevel = 0)
{
    if ($tempLevel < $Nlevel) {
        $tempLevel = $tempLevel + 1;
        $children = User::where('referral_id', $parentId)->get()->pluck('id');
        $count = count($children);
        foreach ($children as $userId) {
            $count += $this->countChildren($userId, $Nlevel, $tempLevel);
        }
        return $count;
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Updated the code to get left, right with or without N Level

```
public function countChildren($parentId, $Nlevel = 0, $legPosition = 0, $tempLevel = 0)
{
    if ($Nlevel) {
        if ($tempLevel < $Nlevel) {
            $tempLevel = $tempLevel + 1;
            if ($tempLevel == 1 && $legPosition) {
                $children = User::where('referral_id', $parentId)
                    ->where('position_to_referral', $legPosition)
                    ->get()->pluck('id');
            } else {
                $children = User::where('referral_id', $parentId)->get()->pluck('id');
            }
            $count = count($children);
            foreach ($children as $userId) {
                $count += $this->countChildren($userId, $Nlevel, $legPosition, $tempLevel);
            }
            return $count;
        }
    } else {
        if ($legPosition) {
            $children = User::where('referral_id', $parentId)
                ->where('position_to_referral', $legPosition)
                ->get()->pluck('id');
        } else {
            $children = User::where('referral_id', $parentId)->get()->pluck('id');
        }
        $count = count($children);
        foreach ($children as $userId) {
            $count += $this->countChildren($userId);
        }
        return $count;
    }
}
```

Call above function to get count :

```
$total = $profileService->countChildren(1); // get total children count of user_id = 1
$totalWith3Level = $profileService->countChildren(1, 3); // get total children count till 3 level
$totalLeft = $profileService->countChildren(1, '', 'left'); // get total children count of left leg
$totalRight = $profileService->countChildren(1, '', 'right'); // get total children count of right leg
$totalLeftWith3Level = $profileService->countChildren(1, 3, 'left'); // get total children count of left leg till 3 level
$totalRightWith3Level = $profileService->countChildren(1, 3, 'right'); // get total children count of right leg till 3 level
```

Comment: Please add the excepted output and what you have tried till now.

Comment: @AkhileshMishra i updated my question with tried solution

Comment: Please post expected output also

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a nested set model make more sense?

```
            1 A 14
              |
      +-------+--------+
      |                |
    2 B 7            8 C 13
      |                |
  +---+---+       +----+----+
  |       |       |         |
3 D 4   5 E 6   9 F 10   11 G 12


user lft rgt
A      1  14
B      2   7
C      8  13
D      3   4
E      5   6
F      9  10
G     11  12
```